# Enable WFS Transaction in geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wfs, wfs-t

I am working in an application to edit attribute and features, for which i am trying to use WFST. I have given write access to all users and for all workspaces.Also,i have changed the service level to 'Transactional' in WFS settings. Restarted the tomcat and tried inserting a feature WFS_transactioninsert.xml in the Demo request. But feature is not being added to the layer. is there anything i need to configure?
[image]
[image]

```
<!--
  YOU PROBABLY DO NOT WANT TO RUN THIS QUERY SINCE 
   IT WILL MODIFY YOUR SOURCE DATA FILES

   It will add a simple line to the tasmania_roads dataset.

    -->
   <wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.0.0"
   xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
   xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"
   xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs 
   http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-transaction.xsd 
  http://www.openplans.org/topp 
  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?typename=topp:tasmania_roads">
  <wfs:Insert>
   <topp:tasmania_roads>
   <topp:the_geom>
    <gml:MultiLineString srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
      <gml:lineStringMember>
        <gml:LineString>
          <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">
           494475.71056415,5433016.8189323 494982.70115662,5435041.95096618
          </gml:coordinates>
        </gml:LineString>
      </gml:lineStringMember>
    </gml:MultiLineString>
     </topp:the_geom>
     <topp:TYPE>alley</topp:TYPE>
    </topp:tasmania_roads>
   </wfs:Insert>
  </wfs:Transaction>
```

[image]

Comment: did you make sure to use a user with write permission, next check the log file to see what the error is, or look in the error message returned - add both to the question

Comment: As you see in the snapshot, i have grant access to all roles

Comment: but did you actually use a role, or are you anonymous?

Comment: Yes seems in the demo request it is 'anonymous'.

Comment: I don't think that will work, use curl (or other tool) to be sure what is happening

Comment: I tried even using CURL and i got a success response message.But when i see the layer in geoserver the feature didn't get added.

Comment: please add the xml you send, the response you get back and the relevant section of the GeoServer log to the question

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Have you tried it from the demo section of geoserver interface?

Comment: Yes i did it in demo as well as by using curl too

Comment: In that case TransactionResult=SUCCESS does not feel right.

Comment: Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with coordinates which do not make sense with EPSG:4326:
Coordinates 494475.71056415,5433016.8189323 494982.70115662,5435041.9509661. I tried inserting with 4326 and insert worked perfectly.